# awk if-then-else statement error

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am writing an if-then-else statement using awk in a bash script.

What I would like to do is identify lines with col 1 values not matching a particular string (rs or chr) and append a prefix (chr) to the col 1 values for those identified lines. All lines with the matched string should print as they were - no appending.

My line of code so far is:

```
awk '{if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)) {($1 == "chr"$1); print $0}}; else {print $0}' filename > newfilename
```

I keep on receiving syntax error messages with this code.

I can perform the identification and the appending successfully on their own but am having problems combining them into one command.

Comment: check where you close that second curly bracket: `'{ if ( this is given) { do this } else { do that } }' `

Answer (score 4):

Here is your code, expanded for viewability:

> ```
> awk '
>     {
>         if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) )
>         {
>             ($1 == "chr"$1);
>             print $0}
>         };
>         else
>         { print $0 }
> ' filename > newfilename
> ```

There are a number of issues with this that spring to mind

1. You're using an equality comparison instead of assignment to try and add the `chr` prefix
2. You have put what should be an assignment in brackets
3. There is an extraneous `}` after the first `print $0`
4. There should be no semicolon before the `else` part
5. You're missing the final close `}` after the code

Here is a fixed version, still expanded:

```
awk '
    {
        if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) )
        {
            $1 = "chr" $1;
            print $0
        }
        else
        { print $0 }
    }
' filename > newfilename
```

And then we can see a simple optimisation to move the repeated `print $0` outside your condition:

```
awk '
    {
        if (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) )
        {
            $1 = "chr" $1
        }
        print $0
    }
' filename > newfilename
```

Since this is basically a simple "condition → amend" you can actually use `awk`'s standard structure to simplify this further. Here we have two `awk` statements, processed sequentially for every line of your input file. The first line prefixes `"chr"` as necessary. The second prints every line.

```
awk '
    (! ($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/) ) { $1 = "chr" $1 }
    1
' filename > newfilename
```

Since this is `awk` it can even be rolled up into a single line, although readability suffers a little

```
awk '(! ($1 ~ /rs|chr/) ) { $1 = "chr" $1 } 1' filename > newfilename
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this line seems to work perfectly:

```
awk '!($1 ~ /rs/ || /chr/) {$1="chr"$1}1'
```

Comment: `($1 ~ /rs/ || /chr/)` will match `$1` for `"rs"`, but `$0` for `"chr"`. You should either `($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)` or `($1 ~ /rs|chr/)`